# Setting up multiple logs with Promtail and Loki, why can I only see 2 jobs in dashboard out of 11 configured?

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I recently setup my log monitoring instance and from my setup, about 11/12 log locations were selected, but when I check my Loki dashboard, I can only see 2 jobs and few directories listed compared to what I configured.

Here is my Promtail config file:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: cronlogs
      __path__: /var/log/cron

- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: auditlog
      __path__: /var/log/audit/audit.log

- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: dnflog
      __path__: /var/log/dnf.log
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: kdumplog
      __path__: /var/log/kdump.log
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: maillog
      __path__: /var/log/maillog
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: mysqllog
      __path__: /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: nginxlog
      __path__: /var/log/nginx/*.log
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: phpfpmlog
      __path__: /var/log/php-fpm/*.log
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: securelog
      __path__: /var/log/secure
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: sssdlog
      __path__: /var/log/sssd/*.log
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: zabbixlog
      __path__: /var/log/zabbix/*.log
```

Jobs visible from Loki dashboard

[image]

Logfiles visible from Loki

[image]

Kindly assist with pointers on what I'm doing wrongly.

I've tried using several methods of setting up multiple log files but result is still same.

Comment: have you resolved this?

Comment: No I have not. The /tmp/positions.yaml shows all the files I need to work with though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need different job_names here, one for each defined static_config. Promtail appears to be using only the parameters for the last static_config with the job_name "system". Grafana/loki may be holding onto previous data which could be why varlogs appeared as a job name there, since it's not defined in your Promtail config.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put the targets under same job name
Something like this:

```
 server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /var/lib/promtail/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: app-logs
    static_configs:
    - targets:
        - loki
      labels:
        job: app-dev-logs
        __path__: "/var/log/retailapps-dev/app-*.log"

    - targets:
        - loki
      labels:
        job: app-prod-logs
        __path__: "/var/log/retailapps-prod/app-*.log"
    
    - targets:
        - loki
      labels:
        job: optidial-logs
        __path__: "/var/log/optidial-dev/app-*.log"
```

also make sure that the files and directories you trying to tail exist. Otherwise you won't see them on grafana